# How to display the content of a JSON file in React?

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, next.js

I have a static JSON file in my public folder and I want to output the content in a React (NextJS) component. Simply display everything as JSON again.

```
import data from '../../public/static/somedata/data.json';

const DummyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div className="box">{data}</div>
  );
};
```

Currently I get the error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child

Is there a way to display raw JSON content in a React component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the work:

```
<div className="box"><pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre></div>
```

Comment: Wow .. I tried this without the further arguments. It works now, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try JSON.stringify()

```
import data from '../../public/static/somedata/data.json';

const DummyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div className="box">{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
  );
};
```